# Adding several folders at once into a playlist in Traktor

Tags: windows-7, traktor

I would like to add several folders at once into a playlist in Traktor. Is there any way to do so?

I use [Traktor Pro 2.6.5](http://www.native-instruments.com/en/products/traktor/dj-software/traktor-pro-2/specifications/) on Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Comment: 1) drag and drop (root folder -> playlist in traktor) 2) right click on the playlist to see whether the contextual menu contains any function for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this within Traktor. However, you can drag and drop several folders from Windows Explorer into a playlist in Traktor.